# Explicit description of all extensions of $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ by $\mathbf{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

In an exercise in my syllabus on homological algebra, I need to explicitly describe what are the $n$ isomorphism classes of extensions of $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ by $\mathbf{Z}$ for the cases $n=p$ prime, $n=pq$ with $p,q$ distinct primes and $n=4$. (The group $\operatorname{Ext}_\mathbf{Z}^1 (\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z})$.)

For $n=p$, I succeeded in classifying these: there are $p$ short exact sequences of the form

$$0\longrightarrow \mathbf Z\stackrel{\times p}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\longrightarrow 0$$
with $f:1\mapsto \overline{a}$ with $a\in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ and we have the split extension

$$0\longrightarrow \mathbf Z\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z \oplus \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\longrightarrow 0$$
which are clearly distinct isomorphism classes.

For $n=4$, I can only find three:

$$0\longrightarrow \mathbf Z\stackrel{\times 4}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z\stackrel{\pi_i}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z\longrightarrow  0$$
where $\pi_1:x\mapsto \overline{x}$ and $\pi_2:x\mapsto \overline{-x}$, and the split extension
$$0\longrightarrow \mathbf Z\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z \oplus \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z\longrightarrow  0.$$

For $n=pq$, we again have the split extension and we can mimic what we did for $p$ prime to obtain $(p-1)(q-1)$ non-equivalent extensions of the form

$$0\longrightarrow \mathbf Z\stackrel{\times pq}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z/pq\mathbf Z\longrightarrow 0$$
with $f:1\mapsto \overline{a}$ with $a\in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}\times \{1,\ldots,q-1 \}$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you only working with abelian groups ?

Comment: @CaptainLama, yes I am looking for short exact sequences of $\mathbf{Z}$-modules.

Comment: If you are familiar with the concept of Baer sum, you can compute them as they are all a multiple of $$0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times n}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$

Comment: @Roland does this Baer sum has anything to do with exercise 11.8 on page 129 of this syllabus? https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/l.d.j.taelman/ca.pdf

Comment: @rae306 Not exactly, but you can also use this exercise. $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ has a structure of abelian group and the multiplication by $n$ correspond to the map induced by $A\xrightarrow{\times n}A$ (or by $B\xrightarrow{\times n}B$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one for $n=4$:
$$0\to\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\to0.$$
In the injection, $1$ goes to $(2,1)$ and in the surjection $(a,b)$ goes to $a+2b$.

In general one will get several extensions with middle term $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$
where $m$ is any divisor of $n$.

Comment: Specifically, one gets $\phi(n/m)$ of those.

Comment: This is exact what I was looking for!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the case for $\mathbf{Z}/pq\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: You'd then have, say $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ in the middle, and one choice for the maps would be $1\mapsto (q,1)$ and $(a,b)\mapsto a+qb$.